# help me please about adjoint of operators in L1

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, adjoint-operators

```
A : L₁→L₁

1) A x=( x₁, x₂,.....xn , 0,0,....)

2) A x= (λ₁ x₁ ,λ₂ x₂,.....)        |λ n|≤1 and λ n ∈ R


I need to find adjoint of operators A in given space.
```

But I am confusing.I know that = What is the y? I can not go any result. I am waiting help. T*y =?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably this is $A:L^2 \to L^2$. Note that the adjoint of $A$, $A^*$, is the operator such that $\langle A x , y \rangle = \langle x, A^* y \rangle$. Write out $\langle A x , y \rangle$, and shuffle the terms out to get a linear operator applied to $y$, and this gives you $A^*$.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should  have $A:L^2\to L^2$.

1)For $x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots),y=(y_1,y_2,\ldots)\in L^2$, we have
$$\langle Ax,y\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i=\langle x,Ay\rangle.$$

So, $A^*=A$.

2)You can check analogously that  $A^*=A$.

Comment: But,we need to use (∑n=1,∞ |x|²)^{1/2} in L2.is it so? I think you want to write L1?